# In Adobe Acrobat 9, how do I use a regex in the JavaScript Console to search the text of a pdf?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, indexing, acrobat

In Adobe Acrobat 9, how do I apply a regex to search the text of a pdf and/or index of a series of pdfs?

There are 200 or so keywords that I need to search, and I could do it manually through each index, but I'll have to do this several times for a lot of indexs/pdfs and want to automate as much as possible.

It's easy enough to search the text of a pdf from the JavaScript console, say for the word 'the':

```
search.query("the","ActiveDoc");
```

And having a regex interact with a string you've written in the console is no problem either:

```
var string="I hope this works9867"
var regex=/\d/

if (regex.test(string))
    {app.alert("win",2)
    }
```

But I can't get a regex to apply to the OCR-ed text of a pdf and have found no guides on how to do so thus far. It seemed logical that either

```
var regex=/\d/

search.query(regex,"ActiveDoc");
```

or some close variant on

```
search.query(/\d/,"ActiveDoc");
```

would work, but no dice. Is there a way to do this? Ideally the method would work for indexes and pdfs alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use regular expressions with `search.query`.
There are two ways you can make searching easier:

Method #1: Put everything you want to search for in an array and pass that to `search.query`.

> myArray = "stuff you want to search for";
>   search.query(myArray, "ActiveDoc");

You could also change the way you want to search by doing something like this:

> search.wordMatching = "BooleanQuery";
>   search.matchWholeWord = false;
>   myArray = "Word1 OR Word2 OR Word3";
>   search.query(myArray, "Folder", "/c/myDocuments");

For more examples of how to configure `search.query`, refer to the [Adobe Javascript API Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JavaScript_SectionPage.70.1.html&accessible=true).

Method #2: Extract the text out of the PDF document and perform a regex search on the string.
The following code loops through the entire document and makes a string of the words on each page and then searches for "Hello" inside the string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.numPages; i++) { // Loop through the entire document
    numWords = this.getPageNumWords(i); // Find out how many words are on the page
    var WordString = ""; // Prepare a string
    for (var j = 0; j < numWords; j++) // Put all the words on the page into a string
    {
        WordString = WordString + " " + this.getPageNthWord(i, j);
    }
    if (WordString.match(/Hello/)) { // Search for the word "Hello" in the string
        search.matchWholeWord = true; // If we got here, we'll search for "Hello" in the document
        search.query(WordString.match(/Hello/), "ActiveDoc");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a very helpful and complete answer, much appreciated. I couldn't get the second proposed solution in Method 1 to work right--it appears to search for literally "Word1 OR Word2 OR Word3" rather than using Boolean syntax. Method 2 was a godsend, though.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Also, I forgot that the BooleanQuery option is ignored when searching the active document, so if you want to do a BoolQuery, you have to change "ActiveDoc" to "Folder" or "Index" and specify the folder or index you want to search in.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, works great now. Btw, is it possible to adapt #2 to run on an index, folder, batch sequence, etc too?

Comment: `numPages`, `getPageNumWords`, etc. are [Doc object properties or methods](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JavaScript_SectionPage.70.1.html&accessible=true). If you don't understand what a Doc object method or property is, I would really recommend trying to *understand* the code above and study JavaScript.

Comment: Definitely--and I _am_ working on that, because I'm interested, but I'm not experienced with JavaScript or programming in general and my boss wants me to tell him if this project is possible or not asap. I do appreciate that you took the time to help out quite a bit, and hopefully will have a better grasp of the material soon.

Comment: Okay, well to let you know, you can easily adapt #2 to run as a batch sequence and the information on how to do that is already provided at the Adobe Acrobat SDK website under "Batch Sequences".